# 'Sign in as Different User' Not "Taking"

Tags: 2007, permissions, user-profile

In some instances of WSS or MOSS when you use the "Sign in as Different User" option, the new login doesn't "take".  Is there any known issue here?  Usually logging out and then logging back in with the second user *does* work.  This seems like a pretty big problem and I've seen it on and off over the years, mostly while testing with different identities.

UPDATE 1: I'm seeing it in several hosted WSS situations, so I don't actually know what authentication they are using.  Interestingly, I *don't* see it in some hosted WSS situations, too.  And consistently within the instance. This might tell us that the authentication method might matter.

UPDATE 2: Another piece of info I should have included in the first place: The reason that I'm asking this is that the [$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser) in SPServices sometimes returns the previous user.  All I'm doing in that function is loading the `_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True` page and pulling the Name from the page. It's the column with the label 'Account', but the InternalName is 'Name':

```
<!--  FieldName="Account"
             FieldInternalName="Name"
             FieldType="SPFieldText"
           -->
```

Here's the SPServices function:

```
// Function which returns the account name for the current user in DOMAIN\username format
$.fn.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser = function() {
    var username = "";
    $.ajax({
        async: false, // Need this to be synchronous so we're assured of a valid value
        url: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True", // Force parameter forces redirection to a page that displays the information as stored in the UserInfo table rather than My Site.
        complete: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseText).find("table.ms-formtable td#SPFieldText").each(function() {
                if(/FieldInternalName=\"Name\"/.test($(this).html())) username = $(this).text();
            });
        }
    });
    return username.replace(/(^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$)/g, '');
};
```

One would like to think that this page would always represent the currently logged in user, but sometimes it represents the *prior* user. Not good.

UPDATE 3:
I may have come up with a fix for this in my SPServices library, at least. It doesn't solve the larger problem that SharePoint seems to have, though.
I added a unique Query String parameter (just the current time) to the call to userdisp.aspx in SPGetCurrentUser per [arunduttgp](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/arunduttgp)'s [suggestion](http://spservices.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=207762). This seems to force the browser to do a hard refresh on the page in the AJAX call, getting the correct values for the logged in user even when the current SharePoint page is showing the prior user incorrectly.

```
 url: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True&" + new Date().getTime(),
```

Comment: Happens to me all the time too while testing. Usually refreshing the page a few times (+/- ctrl key) eventually gets the right identity going. I'm yet to find anything that gives an explanation and haven't had a chance to dig deeper. It almost seems like a credential caching issue of some kind.

Comment: It happens to me a lot as well! One of the tests that I wanted to check was if it happens when the site is using kerberos, ntlm, or both. As we are only using kerberos I can't test that. Not sure if that would really matter.

Comment: In most cases I'm seeing it with NTLM, so that may eliminate that possibility!

Comment: Does this happen with 2010 as well?

Comment: I haven't worked with 2010 enought to know if it happens there, too. Anyone else?

Comment: We experienced this issue after upgrading our desktops from XP to Windows 7. 
For me it didn't seem to be tied to IE 7/IE 8 as I was using IE 8 on XP and didn't have an issue, but as soon as I upgraded to Win 7 with IE8 the problems started.

Answer (score 3):

I get this a lot, just not consistently. A page refresh will sometimes sort it out. I've taken to just using the "runas" command to avoid using "Sign in as Different User" and the associated issues.

```
runas /user:{Domain}\{UserID} [/savecred] "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe [Optional URL]"
```

You can create shortcuts on your desktop to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just refreshing the page is not enough, the majority of times this is simply due to browser caching but a page refresh will not refresh the browser cache.

In IE you would click Cntrl + F5 to clear the cache and do a full refresh, not sure what the same command would be in FireFox or other browsers but the concept will be the same.

Comment: Charles I don't think its a browser caching issue. If there has been content changed on the page, I see the new content. It's just that the logged in identity does not change until the page has been refreshed a few times

Comment: Apologies I only read the question briefly and it read like an easy fix.  I see it in more detail now, although its not something that I have seen before.

Comment: No worries, Charles! I wish it were as simple as a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I see Paul's comment above about seeing the issue more with NTLM. I run Kerberos in the vast majority of my environments, and I very rarely see it at all, so it could be the case where it's related to NTLM.

It's got to be some sort of cache either within the browser or the session. I wouldn't think that there's a way to force a refresh through the script, unless you can refresh the destination URL before reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily have a solution for you (other than the "refresh the page a couple times" others have mentioned, but as a data point I only started seeing this behavior when I first upgraded to IE8.  In fact on machines where I still have IE7, I never see it at all.  I'd be curious if others share this experience.

Comment: I think you're right about IE7... I've never seen it happen with IE6 either! LOL.

Comment: Although I have seen it with FireFox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

A more dependable way to determine the logged on user may be to just ask the server instead of going through SharePoint ( which at this point is acting as a middle man). Getting the variable directly may help with the whole refresh question as there may be some lag as the credentials are updated, guessing here.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) should help. Specifically, the LOGON_USER variable will have the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with same issue of login as Different user not refreshing the page to show the new user and that users permissions. Usually though (Firefox) after a page refresh the correct user and permissions are showing.

But I think a related problem is that if a user lands on the AccessDenied.aspx page and attempts to logon as a different person (using the provided link) it seems to have a similar failure of not updating with the new users permissions and such. Only workaround is to have users close all browser windows and start over by logging in with the correct credentials.

I don't know if this is a new shortcoming of using Windows Integrated Auth and updated browsers holding onto previous credentials or what.

Answer (score 0):

I like Clayton Firth's solution, using the "runas" command.  Any way to make it prompt for the user?  Also, can I run this command from a link within SharePoint?  Essentially I would like to replace the "Sign in as Different User" menu option witht the "runas" command.